# Decorator to transform the return type of a function from a dictionary to a namedtuple

Tags: python, decorator, namedtuple

I wrote a [hack gist](https://gist.github.com/jmborr/da3a0ec8f192c662115f2e35dc24304e) to decorate a function that returns a dictionary so that the dict is transformed into a namedtuple. It has many weak points and I'd like to know from the python gurus if there are other ways for a more robust version

Weak points:

- use of `inspect.getsource` to retrieve the line containing the return. It only works for the last return statement.
- hard-coding all ways in which some could write a statement describing a dictionary. Maybe I'm missing some corner case.
- the name of the `namedtuple` is hard-coded

Comment: If you're looking for a code review, see [codereview.se] (and note that the code to be reviewed must be **in the question**).

Comment: @jwodder Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I'm sorry, I had no idea about [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the `namedtuple` lazily (wait until the first call), you can avoid using `inspect` at all.  You can also choose to pass the name of the namedtuple class as part of the decorator arguments.

```
def namedtuplefy(func, name=None):
    nt = None
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        nonlocal nt
        if nt is None:
            nt = namedtuple(name or (func.__name__ + '_nt'), res.keys())
        return nt(**res)
    return wrapper
```

This will now work even in the case where the wrapped function just bubbles up a dictionary from another function, forms a dictionary in a comprehension from some iterable, etc.

Without `nonlocal`:

```
def namedtuplefy(func, name=None):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if wrapper.nt is None:
            wrapper.nt = namedtuple(name or (func.__name__ + '_nt'), res.keys())
        return wrapper.nt(**res)
    wrapper.nt = None
    return wrapper
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `nonlocal`. It did cost me like 100 lines of useless code

Comment: I had to use a static variable `namedtuplefy.nt` instead of `nonlocal nt` for this to work in python 2.x

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work if you use the decorator on multiple functions.  You might want to consider using `wrapper.nt` instead.

Comment: you're right, I found no problem because I was decorating only one function but it doesn't work when I decorate more functions.  `wrapper.nt` solves this issue, thanks a lot!